# What is the preferred way to write string to file in C++, use '+' or several '<<'?

Tags: c++, string

I am considering writing several lines into a file in C++ using `ofstream` and the text is composed of several parts (strings and numbers), so essentially I know there are two ways.

Here is a simple example:

```cpp
// Way 1 (Use several '<<')
f << str1 << " " << 10 << "Text" << std::endl;
// Way 2 (Use plus to have a continuous string)
f << str1 + " " + std::to_string(10) + "Text" << std::endl;
```

So which one is preferred (or maybe use `append` instead of `+`) in terms of efficiency and other criteria?

Comment: This is an off-topic question.

Comment: @BrainFl Thank you for pointing this out but I do not know why it is off-topic. Please advice.

Comment: @BrainFl Then what the topic appears to be if this is an off-topic question?

Comment: i would expect that not creating a string is more efficient than creating a string. When in doubt about performance you need to measure. What others prefer is indeed offtopic, but I suppose thats jsut a matter of wording the question

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Thank you for your kind advice! I am making some tests in terms of run time.

Comment: @TeddyvanJerry This question is too opinion-based ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic#:~:text=Questions%20which%20are%20too%20broad%2C%20unclear%2C%20incomplete%20or%20primarily%20opinion%2Dbased%20may%20be%20closed%20by%20the%20community%20until%20they%20are%20improved.)).

Comment: @TeddyvanJerry What would "other criteria" be? I agree that this is somewhat opinion based, allthough I think there are objective reasons to prefer `<<`, like not having to worry about the actual datatype or getting a constistent coding style and formatting.

Comment: @BrainFl Oh thank you for that. Maybe I should change its title for example replacing **preferred** as **more efficient** or **less memory**.

Comment: @churill I am not quite sure what a good C++ code should be. Maybe in addition to run time, I assume other things such as **memory** or things I do not know matter as well.

Comment: If performance and memory consumption don't matter, and I/O manipulators are not needed, then either method is equivalent.  Otherwise, the first method has better performance, smaller memory footprint, and allows for I/O manipulators.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wrote a small program that tries both methods, the first version, using `<<` seems to be faster. In any case, the usage of `std::endl` inhibits performance significantly, so I've changed it to use `\n`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <chrono>

int main () {
    unsigned int iterations = 1'000'000;
    std::string str1 = "Prefix string";

    std::ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("example.txt");

    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i=0; i < iterations; i++) {
        myfile << str1 << " " << 10 << "Text" << "\n";
    }
    auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = stop - start;
    std::cout << "Duration: " << duration.count() << std::endl;

    std::ofstream myfile2;
    myfile2.open("example2.txt");

    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i=0; i < iterations; i++) {
        myfile2 << str1 + " " + std::to_string(10) + "Text" << "\n";
    }
    stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    duration = stop - start;
    std::cout << "Duration: " << duration.count() << std::endl;

    myfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

And the output on my machine:

```
Duration: 91549609
Duration: 216557352
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I tested it on my Ubuntu with g++, I got similar results with the first method being much better. However, on my M1 Mac with clang++, the second method is slightly better. Really an interesting question. Does it seem to have many relationships to do with the hardware structure I assume?

Comment: If you dig deep enough you'll find the answer to your question, different compilers on different architectures give different results. You can go to godbolt.org and look at the different assembly code generated with different compilers. Regarding why it runs better on different hardware - who knows? If you dig deep enough - you'll find the answer. 
But remember, "premature optimization is the root of all evil". Good enough should be your guide here.

Comment: Thanks again for your guidance! Now I have a rough understanding of issues like this!

Comment: @TeddyvanJerry as the string you are outputting does not change, a good compiler will optimize away any difference by moving what you are timing out of the loop. Try printing out an ever-increasing number in each iteration of the loop so the compiler can not optimize what you are timing out of the loop.

Comment: `myfile << str1 << " " << std::to_string(i) << "Text" << "\n";` Vs `myfile2 << str1 + " " + std::to_string(i) + "Text" << "\n";`

Comment: @MartinYork Thank you for your reminder. Somehow I got similar results. Maybe the compiler is too genius than I had expected :-)